# Xamarin.Forms - How to check if my app uses the Advertising Identifier (IDFA)?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I'm using Xamarin.Forms. For the iOS app, how to check whether it uses IDFA? I'm about to submit the app for Apple Review in App Store Connect.

For native iOS project (xCode), there were some commands to run like grep in the root path. But how to check this in Xamarin project (Visual Studio for Windows with paired Mac)?

Comment: Do you use any advertisements apis in your project? If not, there is no need to check idfa.

Comment: Hi @JackHua-MSFT, thanks for your reply. Yes, I use Google Admob. But we want to keep ads, disable personalized ads and disable the use of IDFA

Comment: Does you use any api in Google Admob like [requestTrackingAuthorizationWithCompletionHandler](https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/ios14) in the document? If not and you just show ads, IDFA won't be use.